# Triggering event on html element after user clicks on other element with angular / ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just started working on an angular/ionic project. I have a row and when the user clicks on the row I need to trigger a select button that is inside the row.

The html looks like this :

```
<div class="row" ng-click="buttonclick()">
    <div class="col col-25">
      <img class= "icon_bonhomme" ng-src="img/icon_bonhomme.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50 venue1">
      <p class="nb">Nombre de joueurs<br><span style="font-size:10px">Equipes & organisateur inclus</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-25 venue1 nb_player_params">
     <label class="item item-input item-select" style="border-style:none;bottom:4px;width:65px">
       <select id="number-select" ng-model="foot.nb_player" style="position:relative; padding:0; ">
         <option>6</option>
         <option>7</option>
         <option>8</option>
         <option>9</option>
         <option selected>10</option>
         <option>11</option>
         <option>12</option>
         <option>13</option>
         <option>14</option>
         <option>15</option>
         <option>16</option>
         <option>17</option>
         <option>18</option>
         <option>19</option>
         <option>20</option>
         <option>21</option>
         <option>22</option>
         <option>23</option>
         <option>24</option>
         <option>25</option>
         <option>26</option>
         <option>27</option>
         <option>28</option>
       </select>
     </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

So I added a `ng-click="buttonclick()"`on the `div class="row"`.

Then in my controller I added the buttonclick function

```
var footController = angular.module('foot',[]).controller('FootController', function ($confirmation,$scope,$ionicModal,$http,$localStorage,$location,$ionicLoading,$state,$handleNotif,$cordovaGeolocation,$rootScope,$searchLoader, $foot, $ionicPlatform) {

 $scope.buttonclick = function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      console.log("hello");
      $('#number-select').trigger('click');
    });
  }
```

I know the function is triggerd as the console is displaying "hello" but the select button is never triggered.. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#number-select').trigger('onchange');` ?

Comment: just tried it... it doesnt work better